# Regular Expression to remove forward slashes from words not numbers in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove forward slashes separating words, but not numbers in PHP.

Example string:

```
"sf/berkeley to paso/slo/sb on 9/25"
```

I would like my result to be:

```
"sf berkeley to paso slo sb on 9/25"
```

Using `"/([a-z]+)\\/(?=[a-z]+)/"` I am able to get:
"sf berkeley to paso/slo/sb on 9/25"

my PHP code:

```
$re = "/([a-z]+)\\/(?=[a-z]+)/";      
$subst = "$1 ";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use assertions.

```
preg_replace('~(?<=[a-z])/(?=[a-z])~i', ' ', $str);
```

Update:

Your code works, you just need to remove the last `1` parameter, which means do replacing for only one time.

```
$re = "/([a-z]+)\\/(?=[a-z]+)/";      
$subst = "$1 ";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

And also you don't need to add `+` after `[a-z]`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kD8cR7/1)

Comment: I realized this immediately after posting. Clearly, it's time to stop programming for tonight.

Comment: @user1280565: If you use your regex, it will not spot the `/` at the beginning and end of the line. I have come up with another solution based on `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$re = '/^\/|\/$|(?<!\d)(\/)(?!\d)/'; 
$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    if (count($m[1]) > 0) {
       return " ";
    }
    else {
       return "";
    }
}, $str);
echo $result. "\n";
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Gv7Pmq)

The regex - `/^\/|\/$|(?<!\d)(\/)(?!\d)/` - matches `/` at the beginning, or at the end of a string, and replaces them with empty strig, and also matches (and captures just to check the in-string position of `/` we found) a `/` only if there is no digit before it (`(?<!\d)`) and after it (`(?!\d)`).